# Run AsyncTask every X second to update GPS position

Tags: java, android

I have a class that extends `AsyncTask`, which fetches the gps cordinates from the device.

I would like to keep the data updated, so my initial though was to call the class from a timer or a handler. Is this a smart way to implement it, or am i better off listening to the `onLocationChanged` and do my updates in there?

Hope you get the idea, otherwise ill elaborate.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you want to send GPS data on server? If not then your approach to listening to the onLocationChanged() is better one.

Comment: @user370305 Yes, i want to send it to a webservice, but i already have another async class which is ready to send it.

Comment: Use AlaramManager for particular time interval to send GPS data, pass updated GPS data in your AsyncTask which one send it to sever.

Comment: @user370305 Ok, any particular reason why you recommend alarmmanager?

Comment: Yes, Because TimerTask sometimes not works in some device. Also for that you don't have to continuesly monitor for running this, AlarmManager do its own.

Comment: You could use this library to make you're life easier :D

https://github.com/novoda/Novocation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `alarmManager` will be a good solution here.

These allow you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the future.

When an alarm goes off, the Intent that had been registered for it is broadcast by the system, automatically starting the target application if it is not already running.

So when alarm gets triggered, call your `execute()` method of `Async task.`

For more info see this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

I also want to implement the same in my app in near future. If you get the solution, don't forget to update the post about how you implemented it.

Thank you.